# How to add an activity loader inside of the button when clicked the button as a component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show an activity loader like a spinner in the button when a user clicked the Login button with ButtonLoader.js and ButtonLoader.css files. Below is some code from the Login.js and I put  there. I think that the loader will appear If I put some code in ButtoneLoader.js along with a style in ButtonLoader.css, but I don't know where to begin.

Here is the Login Page

[image]

Login.js

```
<div className="auth-form-inputLine auth-form-submitBtn-container" id="auah-login-SubmitBtnContainer">
     <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} className="auth-form-submitBtn">
           {this.state.submitting ? <ButtonLoader /> : <h2 className="text">Login</h2>}
     </button>
</div>
```

I copied the below code from [How to show a loading screen while logging in in React](http:///https://adebola-niran.medium.com/react-loading-screen-while-a-user-is-logging-in-3-steps-bb537031d1d4), but it didn't work. The button only showed a blank which is without a Login text.

Should I change a button style by accessing the class `auth-form-submitBtn` which is the button className?

ButtonLoader.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/ButtonLoader.css";

const ButtonLoader = () => {
  return (
    <div className="spinnerDiv">
        <svg className="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <circle
                className="path"
                cx="25"
                cy="25"
                r="20"
                fill="none"
                strokeWidth="5"
            ></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ButtonLoader;
```

```
ButtonLoader.css

.spinnerDiv {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a background image/color on the webpage?

first thing that pop to mind is maybe adding

```
z-index: 100
```

to the .spinnerDiv {} css

Comment: First, thank you for your help. Yes, there is a background color and I added the image to the question - 'Login Page'. But, adding z-index didn't help to show the loader...

Comment: try adding `color:white` instead of background color for the css. I do not see any errors in the Login.js folder. so this should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try react-spinkit instate

```
Login.js
import Spinner from "react-spinkit";
<div className="auth-form-inputLine auth-form-submitBtn-container" id="auah-login-SubmitBtnContainer">
     <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} className="auth-form-submitBtn">
           {this.state.submitting ? <Spinner name="circle" /> : <h2 className="text">Login</h2>}
     </button>
</div>
```

Choose what spinner you want: http://kyleamathews.github.io/react-spinkit/
And make sure your submitting state is set default to false and change to true in handleFormSubmit function.